# Skipping if statement of two chars compression

Tags: c

I can`t understand why the program skips the if statement inside the for loop even though the characters are identical.

the purpose of the program is to find substring inside another string.

btw, I am new to programming so I hope it's not something stupid ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
    bool isTrue=false;
    char str[50];
    char sub[50];
    int i,j,t;

    printf("Hello please enter a string: ");
    gets(str);
    printf("The substring you want to find: ");
    gets(sub);


    for(i=0;str[i] != 0; i++)
        if(sub[0] == str[i])
            for(j=0, t=i; sub[j] != 0; j++, t++){
                bool isTrue=true;
                if(sub[j]!=str[t])
                    isTrue=false;
            }


    if(isTrue)
        printf("The substring found !");
    else
        printf("No substring");

}
```

Comment: Read about variable scope in your favourite book.

Comment: You have two different objects named `isTrue`. Changing the one inside the loops does not affect the other one. (Hint for gcc: -Wshadow)

Comment: Side notes: 1. Read about why `fgets()` is better than `gets()`. 2. Use blocks even if your then/else statement is one command, same goes for `for` loop. 3. Once you found the substring you can just stop looking for more.

Comment: Thank you I will keep studying.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
bool isTrue=true;
```

Which declares a brand new variable, and hides the previous variable, to this line:

```
isTrue=true;  // Remove the "bool"
```

Which only assigns a value, but does not create a new variable.

Comment: And to detect this kind of mistake on Clang and GCC, use ` -Wshadow`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
    bool isTrue=false;
    char str[50];
    char sub[50];
    int i,j,t;

    printf("Hello please enter a string: ");
    gets(str);
    printf("The substring you want to find: ");
    gets(sub);


    for(i=0;str[i] != 0; i++)
        if(sub[0] == str[i])
            for(j=0, t=i; sub[j] != 0; j++, t++){
                isTrue=true;
                if(sub[j]!=str[t])
                    isTrue=false;
            }


    if(isTrue)
        printf("The substring found !");
    else
        printf("No substring");

}
```

Its basicly your code only that you did in:

```c
for(j=0, t=i; sub[j] != 0; j++, t++){
                bool isTrue=true;
```

But you did declare isTrue in the beginning. So when you do this you are making an isTrue only for this for-loop which is only there changed and not after the loop. Just remove the bool bevore and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just focus on the loop here. This is what I came up with:

```
for(i=0; str[i] != 0; i++){
    if(sub[0] == str[i]){
        isTrue = true;
        for(j=0, t=i; sub[j] != 0; j++, t++){
            if(sub[j]!=str[t]){
                isTrue=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isTrue) break;
    }
}
```

First, you don't want to be re-defining isTrue to true every time in the second loop. You only need to do it once, before the second loop. Second, once it's no longer a substring, you can break out of the second loop. It's not going to magically become true again.

Third, once you've found a substring, you don't need to keep checking. So you can just put that as a check at the end of the first loop.